# How to change the radio button selection in IE 7?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am using Knockout javascript library, and I run into this problem: I am unable to change the radio button selection in IE7.

For example, on my page, I am unable to change the radio button selection using IE 7 the way the [controlTypes example](http://knockoutjs.com/examples/controlTypes.html) does it.

Is there a fix to this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. By adding the name attribute with same value (`name="planetType"`, see below) for all the radio buttons in the group, IE will also be happy...

```html
<label><input type="radio" value="all" data-bind="checked: typeToShow" name="planetType" />All</label>     
<label><input type="radio" value="rock" data-bind="checked: typeToShow" name="planetType"/>Rocky planets</label>     
<label><input type="radio" value="gasgiant" data-bind="checked: typeToShow" name="planetType"/>Gas giants</label>
```